# Restrict Input tags maximum 5 tags

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Hi friends I'm using [this source](https://codepen.io/atomgiant/pen/QWjWgKz) Tags input for my project , but I require only 5 tags to be entered after that it should not allow the tags to be entered into the input field .
The input field can now receive unlimited tags,But I do not know how to limit it

please guide me

Thanks in advance.

```
function tagSelect() {
  return {
    open: false,
    textInput: '',
    tags: [],
    init() {
      this.tags = JSON.parse(this.$el.parentNode.getAttribute('data-tags'));
    },
    addTag(tag) {
      tag = tag.trim()
      if (tag != "" && !this.hasTag(tag)) {
        this.tags.push( tag )
      }
      this.clearSearch()
      this.$refs.textInput.focus()
      this.fireTagsUpdateEvent()
    },
    fireTagsUpdateEvent() {
      this.$el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('tags-update', {
        detail: { tags: this.tags },
        bubbles: true,
      }));
    },
    hasTag(tag) {
      var tag = this.tags.find(e => {
        return e.toLowerCase() === tag.toLowerCase()
      })
      return tag != undefined
    },
    removeTag(index) {
      this.tags.splice(index, 1)
      this.fireTagsUpdateEvent()
    },
    search(q) {
      if ( q.includes(",") ) {
        q.split(",").forEach(function(val) {
          this.addTag(val)
        }, this)
      }
      this.toggleSearch()
    },
    clearSearch() {
      this.textInput = ''
      this.toggleSearch()
    },
    toggleSearch() {
      this.open = this.textInput != ''
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (tag != "" && !this.hasTag(tag) && this.tags.length < 5) this.tags.push(tag)`. I believe you should be able to look for the entries of your tags array. If it's less than 5, then you can push to the array, otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

You could update the `fireTagsUpdateEvent()` function to disable the input when there are 5 (or more) tags

```
fireTagsUpdateEvent() {
  this.$refs.textInput.setAttribute('disabled', this.tags.length >= 5)
  this.$el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('tags-update', {
    detail: {
      tags: this.tags
    },
    bubbles: true,
  }));
},
```